# Swift Default Parameter value with Delegate Reference

Tags: ios, swift, swift4

I am trying to do dependency injection in my code without using any framework, while refactoring I tried to pass dependency from outside. Now issue which I am facing is declaration of delegate which is needed for default parameter value.

```
init(service : MYService = MYService(withDelegate: self)) {

}
```

In above snippet, above object creation needs delegate from outside to transfer results. In Swift is their any way to declare that self reference in parameter.

Technically it seems like at this point self is not created as this is init method, now I have another option which I would like to go with if there is no another way for achieving it.

That is creating `MYService` object without delegate and I have to expose another method for accepting delegate.

Comment: Have you tried making a convenience init where you initialize MYService and then call the normal initializer?

Comment: Could it work if the delegate was declared as `lazy`?

Comment: @JoakimDanielson No, that won't work as error is in default parameter which is before initialising delegate.

Answer (score 0):

It seems a good approach to inject any service as i hope the `MYService` `class` also conform to some `protocol` so that any service can be injected that conform to that `protocol`. Specific to this question i would like to recommend keep the delegate also as an injectable object as below,

```
init(service: MYService = MYService(), serviceDelegate: MyServiceDelegate? = nil) {
   if let delegate = serviceDelegate {
      service.delegate = delegate
   } else {
      service.delegate = self
   }
}
```

For this, you have to expose service `delegate` which should be totally fine as this is how we have in `Swift` (`UITableView`, `UITextField` etc)

As i think you want to make the `class` that owns `service` as default `delegate` so i made the `delegate` as `optional` so that if its not there, this class will be the delegate otherwise if it will be the `delegate` passed along `initialization`.

Comment: Yes MyService follows Protocol which supposed to pass in parameter. For the sake of clear description I just used class directly. Passing delegate after init is another option if I don't found anything for my issue. Thank you!!